# Checking for null values in Java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to modify an Android app that is pulling some JSON from a server..

```
JSONObject mResult = new JSONObject((String) result);
```

Then using that to construct an object from my Sponsor class..

```
Gson mGson = new Gson();
mSponsor = mGson.fromJson(mResult.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("sponsor").toString(), Sponsor.class);
```

Sponsor class is just a shell with setters and getters, no logic done. Something like this:

```
public class Sponsor {

    @SerializedName("address1")
    private String Address1;
    @SerializedName("address2")
    private String Address2;

    public Sponsor(String address1, String address2) {
        Address1 = address1;
        Address2 = address2;
    }

    public Sponsor() {
        Address1 = "";
        Address2 = "";
    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return Address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        Address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return Address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        Address2 = address2;
    }
}
```

The app puts the address in a TextView like so:

```
txtAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_sponsor_address);
txtAddress.setText(mSponsor.getAddress1() + "\n" + mSponsor.getAddress2());
```

This all works, except when the server returns `null` for `address2`, in which case the literal text "null" is printed in the TextView where address2 should be.

My question is how can i get rid of the "null"?

I've tried a few different things, started with a simple ternary statement and got more and more verbose and nothing has worked so for.

Here is the latest and most ridiculous-looking thing I've tried so far:

```
String addr2 = ((String) mSponsor.getAddress2()).trim();
String a2;
if((addr2 == "null") || (addr2 == "")) a2 = (String) "";
else a2 = (String) addr2;

txtAddress.setText(mSponsor.getAddress1() + "\n" + a2);
```

This causes the app to crash when I open that Activity.

I'm a noob at Java so please provide references if you can.

Comment: Have you tried `addr2.equals("null")` or `addr2 == null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"getAddress2()" isn't returning the literal string "null".  It's returning a `null` reference and the StringBuilder is converting it to a "null" String when you print it in the concatenation.  That's why it crashes when you try to trim the word.

A simple way to fix it is to put the ternary operator in the getter itself like so:

```
public String getAddress2() {
  return (Address2 == null) ? "" : Address2;
}
```

Now you'll never return a null reference and you can safely use it without any checks.

Comment: Maybe this is a separate question, but wouldn't the `public **String**` part guarantee that a String is returned?

Comment: It guarantees that an object that is returned will implement a `String` interface. That means, if it exists, you can perform the `String` methods on said object. The object that is returned may not actually exist though (hence `null`). If the object doesn't exist, then you can't perform operations on it. Java doesn't have any way of guaranteeing that a non-null is returned. You have to guarantee that through the interface because sometimes a null is appropriate. For example, in this scenario, how do you know the server returned a "null" and not an empty string? You do lose that information.

Comment: Most commonly though you would return a default object like an empty String so you don't have to sprinkle "if(obj != null)" everywhere in the code (that gets old really, really fast).

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. I'm now comfortable with using this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could create another getter in your `Sponsor` class, where you'd put your logic to get a formatted address :

```
public String getFormattedAddress() {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Address1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Address2)
        && !Address1.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && !Address2.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
      return (Address1 + "\n" + Address2);
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Address1) && !Address1.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
      return (Address1);
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Address2) && !Address2.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
      return (Address2);
    }
    return ("");
}
```

And then simply setText with :

`txtAddress.setText(mSponsor.getFormattedAddress());`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get most of what you're doing, pretty self-explanatory, but can you please briefly tell me what `TextUtils` is? Do I need to import that?

Comment: @PootieTang  TextUtils is a utility class that's part of the Android SDK so you don't have to add it to the dependencies.

Comment: `TextUtils` is part of the android text imports, which checks for null or empty String. Simply import `import android.text.TextUtils;`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use :

```
if((addr2 == "null")
```

For string comparaison use:

```
if (addr2.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String addr2 = mSponsor.getAddress2();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(addr2) || !addr2.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
     txtAddress.setText(mSponsor.getAddress1() + "\n" + addr2);
else
     txtAddress.setText(mSponsor.getAddress1());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
// if null, addr2="", if not null, addr = getAddress2()'s result 
String addr2 = mSponsor.getAddress2() == null ? "" : ((String) mSponsor.getAddress2()).trim();

txtAddress.setText(mSponsor.getAddress1() + "\n" + addr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `getter` code:

```
 public String getAddress2() {
    if (Address2.equals("null")) {
        Address2="";
    }
    return Address2;
 }
```

Of course, you can do the same with your other `getter` for `Address1`.
Also, if you want to check for an empty string, use `Address2.length() == 0` as opposed to `Address2 == ""`.